# ReactJS passing a prop that the element owns to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return a `<li>` element with an eventListener. But I want the `<li>` to pass a property it owns to a function onClick. This is specifically what I am talking about:

```
return (<li onClick={this.changeTab(tab_id)} tab_id={index + 1} <a href="#">{obj.display_name}</a></li>);
```

But if you do something like this, you receive the `error: Uncaught ReferenceError: tab_id is not defined`

As you can see, `tab_id` is owned by the `li`.Is there a way my component can pass that property? Here is my full component for context:

```
var MainMenu = React.createClass({
                changeTab: function(tab_id){
                    this.props.dprops.changeTab(tab_id)
                }, 
                render: function() {

                    var categories = this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj, index){
                        return (<li onClick={this.changeTab(tab_id)} tab_id={index + 1} <a href="#">{obj.display_name}</a></li>);   
                    });
                    return (<ul><li className="active"><a href="#">All Videos</a></li>{categories}</ul></div>

                        </div>);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Also you didn't close your opening li after `tab_id={index + 1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the **variable** `tab_id` doesn't exist anywhere. You are trying to call `this.changeTab(tab_id)`, where `tab_id` is not defined.

There are two mistakes here:

- You are trying to access a variable that is not defined.
- You are *calling* the event handler instead of *passing* it to `onClick`.

A simple solution would be to use `.bind` to create a new function with bound argument:

```
onClick={this.changeTab.bind(this, index + 1)}
```

The disadvantage is that this creates a new function every time the component rerenders.

You could solve this by creating a component that represents the list item instead. That component would pass its `tab_id` prop to its `onClick` prop.

Example:

```
var ListItem = React.createClass({
    _onClick: function() {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.tabID);
    },

    render: function() {
        return <li onClick={this._onClick}>{this.props.children}</li>;
    }
});

// and in the MainMenu#render method

this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj, index) {
  return (
     <li onClick={this.changeTab} tabID={index + 1} >
       <a href="#">{obj.display_name}</a>
     </li>
  );
}, this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that I had to do it this way instead. Though, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`. Why is `this.changeTab` out of scope in my return? Any solution this?

Comment: Oh, you also have to bind the the `.map` callback. Simply pass `this` as second argument to `.map`: `this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj, index){ ... }, this);`.